# Show that (P→Q) ∨(Q→R) is a tautology

Tags: logic, proof-writing

I don't really understand Tautologies or how to prove them, so if someone could help, that would be great!

Comment: What method are you expected to use?  The more-or-less-automatic method is to use a truth table.

Comment: They didn't specifically state wether we can use a truth table or not, but all the other solution in that section do not use truth tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Truth table method**:
$$\matrix{
  p&q&r&p\to q&q\to r&\hbox{answer}\cr
  T&T&T&T&T&T\cr
  T&T&F&T&F&T\cr}$$
and so on.  You can provide six more rows yourself and check that the final answer is always true.

**Logical equivalences method**:
$$\eqalign{
  (p\to q)\vee(q\to r)\quad
  &\Leftrightarrow\quad (\neg p\vee q)\vee(\neg q\vee r)\cr
  &\Leftrightarrow\quad (q\vee\neg q)\vee (\neg p)\vee r\cr
  &\Leftrightarrow\quad {\bf T}\vee (\neg p)\vee r\cr
  &\Leftrightarrow\quad {\bf T}\ .\cr}$$

Saving the best to last. . . **smart idea method**: $q$ is either true or false.  If $q$ is true then $p\to q$ is true; if $q$ is false then $q\to r$ is true.  In either case, $(p\to q)\vee(q\to r)$ is true.

Comment: Thank you!! The logical equivalences method is what I think they were looking for. This makes a ton of sense!

Answer (score 0):

If $Q$ is true, then $P\to Q$ is true, and we're done.

If $Q$ is false, the $Q\to R$ is true, and we're done.

But to go back to basic definitions, a tautology is something that is true in **every** row of the truth table.  In this case there are eight rows.  Look at each row and ascertain whether the proposition in question is true.
\begin{array}{ccc}
P & Q & R \\
\hline
T & T & T \\
T & T & f \\
T & f & T \\
f & T & T \\
T & f & f \\
f & T & f \\
f & f & T \\
f & f & f
\end{array}

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of tautologies! Explained it much better than my professor did.

Answer (score 0):

If Q is true, the first implication is true, so the disjunction is true.

If Q is false, the second implication is true, so the disjunction is true.

In either case, the disjunction is true, *quod erat demonstrandum.*